# How to Insert Row in current Page Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

How To insert Row in current Page doesn't matter at first Or End Current Page 
 `orderDetailsTable = $("#orderDetailsTable").DataTable({...});
with datatable orderDetailsTable.row.add({
                    "rowNum": '',
                    "orderDetailsId": '',
                    "productName": '',
                    "productUnit": '',
                    "quantity": '',
                    "unitPrice": '',
                    "total": '',
                    "actions": '',
                }).draw(false);
                orderDetailsTable.order([1, 'asc']).draw();
                orderDetailsTable.page(orderDetailsTable.page()).draw(false);`
 this code add row at the end page ...

Comment: with datatable orderDetailsTable.row.add({
                    "rowNum": '',
                    "orderDetailsId": '',
                    "productName": '',
                    "productUnit": '',
                    "quantity": '',
                    "unitPrice": '',
                    "total": '',
                    "actions": '',
                }).draw(false);
                orderDetailsTable.order([1, 'asc']).draw();
                orderDetailsTable.page(orderDetailsTable.page()).draw(false);

Comment: Prepare required html like '<tr><td></td></tr>' as per your requirement dynamically and just append into databale using 'append' method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var line = '<tr><td>Some content</td></tr>'; //put the row content in variale
$('#my_table>tbody').append(line); // And append this variale (your new row) to the table body.
```